# evaporate js with php signing url for s3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-s3, evaporate.js

I'm trying to use this:

https://github.com/uqee/angular-evaporate

to create a multipart uploader.  The issue I'm having is creating the signature since I'm using PHP.  Are there any working examples anyone could point me to?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below links having example setup for evaporate js with php

http://rjv.im/post/91133470306/using-evaporatejs-with-laravel-php
https://github.com/rajivseelam/laravel-resumable